# Are two "AuthType" directives possible in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd

I need to protect my site with basic authentication, but I have already an authentication directive with shibboleth:

```
<Location />
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequireSession Off
  require shibboleth
</Location>
```

Can I add basic authentication somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could use both Shibboleth and Basic authentication... Shibboleth already provides its own authentication mechanism.  You'd probably need to remove the first one.

```
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Now, if you don't know why Shibboleth is there, you should probably contact the previous/current system administrator to make sure you won't block some previously-allowed people from accessing the website.